# Convince a skeptic! Why do I need a "Roles" table in my database?

Tags: database-design, user-roles

When designing the database tables for storing simple User/Role information, can anyone tell me why it would be a bad idea to store the Role information directly on the User table (for example, Comma-Separated in a Roles column).

Thoughts:

1. The database doesn't need to know about the roles, that's the UI's domain
2. The quicker the access to a specific user's roles the better
3. Sure, if sometime in the future I want access to all of the users for a specific role the query might

be a little slow, but who cares at that point?

Does this make any sense? Am I off my rocker? Wouldn't creating Roles and UserRole tables be overkill and add unnecessary sql and code overhead?

UPDATE:

To further illustrate my point... in code, I want to know if user "Steve" is in role "Administrator".

Option 1: query the UserRole table for a list of roles for user "Steve". Loop through that list and see if the RoleName matches "Administrator".

Option 2: split the csv in the User's Role property and see if the resultant list contains "Administrator"

UPDATE II:

I agree that my suggestion violates all sorts of "best practice" type thinking, particularly around DB design. However, I am not seeing how the "best practices" make any sense in this sort of scenario. I do like to rock the best practices boat now and then...I like to code in a way that seems smart, which means sometimes I need to understand more to know when I'm not being smart :)

Comment: Those updates (Option 1 and Option 2) . . . Nobody writes queries like that.  If you want to know whether "Steve" is in the role "Administrator", `SELECT RoleName from UserRole where user = 'Steve' and RoleName = 'Administrator';`. That query should return one row if Steve's an administrator, no rows if he's not. No looping. No splitting. (You could just as easily return the user's name or an integer or a Boolean instead. Again, no looping and no splitting.) It troubles me that this is very, very basic--it's something I'd expect an unpaid intern to get right every time. But you got it wrong.

Comment: @Catcall - Don't be so harsh, there are senior developers and "enterprise" applications written in this manner.  A lot of people rush and end up following this specific approach.  It's a very simple design so for someone like @Steve it seems like the best choice and it almost seems like a logical choice if you don't think about it in a set based solution.  Ultimately it will be his decision to create this functionality, but we are here for guidance / suggestions.  To say it's basic and an intern "gets" it doesn't help at all.

Comment: @JonH: A lot of things seem logical if you don't think about them. Most programmers find that "not thinking" doesn't scale well. And I didn't only say "it's basic and an intern 'gets' it"; I first provided one version of the correct query. If Steve is going to design and build a usable database, he's going to need to get the basics right. In SQL, you don't get much more basic than learning how to use a WHERE clause.

Comment: @Catcall: I made a mistake in the sql query example, you are right. I was combining thinking about "GetAllRolesForUser" while thinking about "IsUserInRole". Believe it or not I do know how to write a simple WHERE clause -- I'm glad this post isn't an attempt to convince someone to hire me. As far as "not thinking" -- if I was going to "not think" I would have gone right ahead with the standard set of Roles tables, but I was attempting to understand the "WHY" behind that standard. Perhaps I worded the question wrong OR SO isn't the place for discussing design concepts?

Comment: a) "As far as 'not thinking'" . . . I was responding to JohH, not to you. b) Some people do seem to vote to close design questions, but I'm not one of them. There's a lot more to programming than writing and debugging code. c) The dbms is the only piece of software that can guarantee that integrity constraints are consistently applied to *all* users and *all* applications. (See my earlier answer below.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it violates 3rd normal form.  You want to seperate all of your entities as different objects which means you need a seperate table, as well as a relationship table.

### Violation of data

If you keep all of this in one table you are placing too much irrelevant information about a user in a user's table.  A user's table should have fields that pertain only to that user, such as their name, user account, etc.  But in this case you've decided to throw in some role information.  This doesn't make sense as you are adding attributes that do not necessairly have anything to do with a user.

The result is you start adding fields that do not pertain to a user, and you end up having a ton of unrelated information.  The solution to this is have a users table like so:

```
User table
UserID
User
...

Role table
RoleID
Role
....

User Role Table (the relationship)
UserRoles
UserID
RoleID
...
```

### Updating / Inserting of data

The next issue you have to deal with if you store role information inside of a user's table is how to perform valid updates, inserts.  This makes it all the more difficult.  When you edit a record, you have to ensure you edit the right value from the CSV.

### Finding the right role

Here lies the most difficult problem, how to find the role given a user.  You might come up with this great parsing technique in C# or SQL Server, it works great..but it becomes terribly slow and hard to read.  You start dealing with `SubString()`, `Left()`, `Right()`, `Len()` and a whole slew of other functions just to parse out the role of a user.

## The Solution

You may think that putting it all into one table is easier right now.  It probably will take a lot less up front time.  But you have to develop applications with the future in mind.  The UI will be much simplier if you follow the rules of 3nf and create a nice relational structure.  Not only will the UI admin screens look nice, but getting a role for a specific UserID will be so trivial, as opposed to parsing or searching...

Comment: Why does "role" need to be an "entity" in the database though? Is this because it's standard for the "database" to be in control instead of the "business rules" themselves? (Meaning the database just stores data and the application(s) can operate on the data per their own business rules defined in code.)

Comment: @Steve - Somewhere you have to store the roles, why would you want to hard code roles in your actual application.  In this case, you are forced to redistribute / reupload your application depending on the type (client / web / etc).  The role's may increase or decrease, so you should be able to add / delete entries from the data layer, after all a role is a piece of data no?  If you end up putting this in the application framework you are going to make your life a living hell :).

Comment: @Steve - today your db doesn't need to know about roles, tomorrow everything changes, plan for the future and develop the system wisely.  Take the hit now and do the work correctly before the hit becomes a nightmare.

Comment: Putting multiple values in a single comma separated field actually violates first normal form.  It's a repeating group.  I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: @JonH -- please see my updates to the question. Getting a role for a user seems more trivial "my" way, not less -- am I missing something? I'm not a fan of putting smarts in the db data, I've seen lots of problems with flexibility later on, so I prefer "dumb data" with meta-data and business rules that make that data worth something.

Comment: @Steve - I give up, do it your way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a great plan.  Suppose you're manually updating someone's roles and you type the name of a role slightly wrong?  If you had a separate table, a database constraint would warn you.  Suppose you decide to change the name of a role?  If you had a separate table, you would only need to change it in one place.

Database normalization is done for good reasons; it's not just nitpicky.  You wouldn't repeat key code in your codebase in more than one place; database denormalization is the equivalent.

EDITED TO ADD:
You make the point that the application is ultimately going to make decisions based on the values returned by the database; e.g. granting certain options if the user has a role called "Admin".  This is true, and it is another, separate place where the consistency of, for example, role names can go awry.  I don't think denormalizing the database makes this less likely.

One good approach to help with this (and a good way to implement authorization in general) is to have a single location in code where the role is translated into certain general abilities (e.g. admins can read and write all entities, guests can read certain entities and can't write anything, etc.).  Then, in the many places where you need to establish access, you check against an ability, rather than checking against a role.

That is to say, in a view, if you're deciding whether to show the "edit" button on the description of an item, you don't check by doing `if role=='ADMIN' or role=='EDITOR'`, you check by doing `if user.can_edit(item)`.  Somewhere else you've established that admins and editors get the ability to edit items. See, for example, the approach that the Rails authorization system [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan#readme) uses.

Using this approach, there's only one place where you're referencing the names of roles (e.g. in CanCan you have a class called "abilities" which defines all of the rules for who can do what, based on their roles.  Everywhere else, you reference what abilities a user has to determine what they can do or see.

Comment: I agree with the concept, but I'm wondering why the database needs to care? My application HAS to know about the roles because it has to present the roles to the UI and has to enforce the business rules associated with the various roles. So why not just have the roles defined in the application and only in the application? (Instead of the application having to ask the DB what the roles are and mapping the DB roles to something the application knows about, etc.)

Comment: If you wanted to hard-code the roles into the application, I could see your point.  Although that would of course be a terrible idea, as roles frequently need to change on the fly.  But if the roles are data (and they are) then I think they should be treated as data, which includes not repeating data that doesn't need to repeat.  It's not a matter of the database governing the application, it's just a matter of setting up the data so that you can enforce logical consistency.

Comment: At some point I *have to* hard-code role data in my application, right? I have to make decisions in code based on role data, so at some point I have to know that "100001" is a "Administrator"

Comment: Nope.  The role table has an actual role name in it, so you use the role ID to join the user to the role, and use the role name to know who is an administrator.  NEVER NEVER reference database ID's in your code; they are likely to be different from one database instance to another (e.g. from a test to a production instance of an application).

Comment: @JacobM Yes, good point. So, somewhere my application has to know that "Administrator" role is equal to the DB Role with the Role Name of "Administrator" :) Either I am going to have hard-coded decision points with the magic string of "Administrator" or I am going to have an enum of some sort that I use for making decisions in the code -- that's the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: I started responding in a comment, but had a lot to say, so I edited my answer to respond.

Comment: @JacobM - kudos for the link to CanCan, that's the sort of smart code thinking I'm interested in. I don't, however, see how that makes storing roles in the database beneficial. The CanCan methodology seems to me to be putting the smarts and the power in the code, not the DB...

Comment: The CanCan approach means that there's a single point of interface between the names of roles in the code and the names of roles in the database.  Whether you use the normalized approach or not, you'll have the potential of inconsistency, so the CanCan approach minimizes those possible errors.  My intent was to counter your point about the need to "hard code" the names of roles in your code somewhere -- yes, you have to do that (whether you normalize or don't), but you can minimize it through this approach.  In a CanCan-based app, the word "ADMIN" appears exactly once in code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need extra logic to parse your CSV at the code side.
2. Most ORM does not support CSV.
3. If you have a long role name (ex. UserWhoHaveAccessToXObjButNotYObjAndAtTheSameTimeCanDoZ) then you are wasting space repeating it for all the users.

Also, your first assumption does not hold for all situations. What if MY database need to know about roles?

Comment: My code is going to have to translate the information from the database anyway, so passing the csv to a role provider shouldn't be any extra work: in fact it may be less work in code. Point 3 is an interesting consideration...However, if space is cheap and speed is king, would requiring the extra tables and joins be worth it?

Comment: @Steve - That's the great thing about databases, they are relational, so joins are very very normal.  I've seen posts where people mention whether or not to create these huge tables to avoid joins.  The answer is you DONT avoid joins in a database, they are a feature that should be used because at the end of the day it is RELATIONAL data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want the Database Management system to manage the data or you want the application to manage the data.  In most cases, the DBMS does a better job, because that's what it's built for.

Comment: I tend to agree with @WalterMitty.  The job of the database is to store and secure the data just like a bank stores your safty deposit box.  The bank does not require me to place my items in any paticular order in the box which allows me to apply my business rules to the box's contents.  If the data will be used only by the application per the application design then just store it in the pattern the desing doc states, string, numbers etc and give it to them just like they gave it to you to store.  If the DB must use it for business rules DO NOT store it in a comma string.

Answer (score -1):

You said

> So why not just have the roles defined
>   in the application and only in the
>   application?

You can do that reliably only if you can truthfully say, "I'm 100% certain that every programmer and every database administrator will manually preserve data integrity perfectly no matter what application touches this database, no matter what language it's programmed in, no matter how experienced or inexperienced the programmer is, and no matter how complex the database becomes, from now until the end of its life."

If you get to the point in your career where you manage a programming project, part of your job will be assigning coding responsibilities to the persons best suited to carry them out. At the architectural level, someone also assigns program responsibilities--like data integrity--to the module or subsystem best suited to carry them out. Data integrity can only be *guaranteed* by assigning that responsibility to the dbms. Assigning it to any other part of the system, whether code or human, is just an expression of hope, and hope doesn't scale well.

Comment: And the chances of that happening is very very rare...-1 prepare for optimal solutions because 10 years from now there may be 10 new developers on this assignment.  Make their lives easier.

Comment: No, right *now* you probably have at least three applications that have access to your database. You have your application code, the dbms graphical UI, and the dbms command-line UI. It's not uncommon for application developers to believe they can do the dbms's job as well as the dbms can. They're usually wrong.